# how can I add a css for my plugin in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, themes

This question may seem too dummy, I found the info on codex (its my first project on wordpress) and I want this style to be for the admin and for the frontend... they wrote I can use this

```
wp_register_style( 'uni-bootstrap', DS.'plugins'.DS.'uni-info'.DS.'css'.DS.'bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style('uni-bootstrap');
```

I even named a DS variable, in case is linux or windows (directory slash) , still, I look on the loaded page, and the route is correct, but no slashes. I try to write them by my own with "/" and still, no success..

I get the absolute path, but when I see what it loads it says `UNDEFINED`

So, I changed and try other way(for the admin only)

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'admin_css' );
function admin_css(){
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MYPATH">';
}
```

Still, the same UNDEFINED result, I really dont know how to load it, and how to use the paths, due I dont know how wordpress manage the folders and so on, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_styles' );

function register_plugin_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'my-plugin', plugins_url( 'my-plugin/css/plugin.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin' );
}
```

and for admin

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_styles' );
```